# Is it possible to convert object to table in Specflow feature

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

For example I need a specflow feature which is like :

Given a user:

|ID|FirstName|LastName|

|3 | Jack | Sparrow |

Is it possible to have a form for example :

**Enter first row:**

**Enter Second row:**

**Enter user informations:**...

Then this form will give me

**|ID|FirstName|LastName|**

**|......| ...... | ......|**

Is it possible to convert C# object(table rows) to Specflow feature table?

Comment: Semih, this question isn't entirely clear to me. Are you asking to pop up a form while the scenario is running, in lieu of having a table in the scenario? Are you asking how to match a C# form to Specflow's table? Is the form in WPF, or are you using C# to serve HTML and talking about a web form? Please can you clarify?

Comment: I just want  a form that will give me random text as a |ID|FirstName|LastName| |......| ...... | ......| format when i enter specific columns(ID,FirstName,LastName and also their real life data e.g |3|Semih|Rock| (also I will enter this data in the form).This form will give me for example a text 
|ID| FirstName | LastName |

|5  | Semih       | Rock       |

|6  | Lunivore   | Stone      | (Imagine I enter ID,FirstName,LastName as headers and Semih,Lunivore for data ) Is that clear ?

Comment: No, not clear. I think we probably need some minimal code that shows what you're trying to achieve and where you're stuck. If you can write the code you want to wrap the SpecFlow around... well, that's not the way BDDers would normally do it, but it's a great way to learn and a good way to show us where you're stuck. What do you have? Can you show us a couple of examples of where "random text" appears? Do you have an example of what you think a form might look like?

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/X5qYcG5/Bddconvertion.png

I tried to explain it via paint. 
I am curious about how BDDers would normally do ?
Thanks

My main goal is to keep programmer create table via form not by writing every line in keyboard(If you have 1000 employee that would be hard to do)

Comment: Semih, sorry to take a while to get back to you. It sounds like what you're doing is not creating examples to illustrate behaviour, but allowing people to verify that the examples they are thinking of will work? If that's the case, I think that maybe the underlying automation tools (Selenium, etc.) will work well for you, but you're stepping outside the BDD tools. I'm thinking a framework like ApprovalTests working with Selenium might be better for you.

Either way, it doesn't sound like it can be solved here. Please do post on the BDD group as we all have experience of automation too.

Comment: Thank you, I will ask how BBDers would normally do.